# positive invertible elements in some $C^*$ algebra

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, positive-definite

Suppose we take $A=B(H)$,where $H$ is a complex Hilbert space.Let $S,T$ be two positive invertible elements in $A$,$K=\{m>0,S\leq m T\}$, when $dim(H)=1$,it is easy to see that $K$ has a minimum,when $dim(H)=n$,$S,T$ can be viewed as two $n\times n$ postive invertible real matrices.

If $dim(H)\geq 2$,does there must exist a minimal elment in $K$?

Answer (score 0):

The set $K$ is always of the form $[r,\infty)$ for some $r\geq0$.

To see the above, let $r=\inf K$. For any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $r_1\in K$ with $r_1<r+\varepsilon$. Then, for any vector $x\in H$, 
$$
\langle Sx,x\rangle\leq\langle r_1Tx,x\rangle\leq\langle (r+\varepsilon)Tx,x\rangle\leq\langle rTx,x\rangle+\varepsilon\langle Tx,x\rangle. 
$$
As this works for any $\varepsilon$, we get that $S\leq rT$.

Comment: $K$ is obviously connected. If $m,n\in K$ and we take the segment $tm+(1-t)n$ then $$\langle Sx,x\rangle=t\langle Sx,x\rangle+(1-t)\langle Sx,x\rangle\leq t\langle mTx,x\rangle+(1-t)\langle nTx,x\rangle=\langle [tm+(1-t)n]Tx,x\rangle.$$

Comment: Again: $K $ is connected. So if $K $ is not connected, you can conclude anything you want.